# What is this growing on my orange tree

Tags: identification, trees, diagnosis, fruit-trees, diseases

I was adding root stimulator to my orange tree today and noticed this spot on the stem.  Can anyone tell me what it is?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Edit:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an old mower wound.  If you are trying to get your tree to produce more support roots, a thicker trunk, I would get rid of the staking stuff. When a tree is able to move in the slightest bit of wind that causes the best support root growth and definitely thickens the trunk.  Is there a reason you are trying to support this tree?

Think of a broken arm or leg.  What does that limb look like when the cast is removed?  Thin, weak, atrophied.  I only stake newbie bare root trees and older trees that have been blown over.  I walk through parking lots and clip the staking stuff on trees.  Makes a huge difference in growth and sturdiness.

I am also a bit worried your tree was planted too deeply.  Could you pull the soil and bark away from the trunk of your tree to make sure only the roots are covered?  Any mulch, soil against the bark of the trunk will enhance bacteria that will easily girdle your tree and kill it.

Comment: A quick question for you @stormy.  Do you mean removing the gray stake right next to the tree?  That was with the tree when I got it from the nursery.  I've had it in the ground for half a year and I didn't know when I should remove it.  I went and removed the dirt and mulch till I came across a little root then moved the dirt back on top.  I then made a little basin around the tree that ended a good 2-3 inches from the trunk.  That's how it was originally and time/weather had pushed the mulch back against the tree.

Comment: Remove that stake.  Absolutely.  Could you take a picture of the base of that trunk where you pulled the mulch/soil away?  Even if this mulch/soil were only 1/4 inch above the surface of the soil and on this trunk, that is enough to eventually kill your tree.  Sounds like you have done a great job...I would take it back another foot and keep an eye out for the mulch sloughing back towards the trunk.

Comment: I have updated the post with the new pictures @stormy